# Create a page for useful links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, help-center

A lot of the time, it's handy to use outside resources to post information relevant to a question or answer, like [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) or [Pastebin](https://www.pastebin.com).

On the one hand, link rot is a consideration, but would it be worthwhile to add a "useful links" page to the Help Center?

Answer (score 2):

There is such a page: the tag wiki. It has the advantage of being 'context aware', e.g. SQLFiddle is very relevant but only when you're working with SQL. It's mentioned in the [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), along with its competitors:

> #### Online Testing

> While you should always provide [complete code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g., schema, data sample and expected result) in your question or answer, you can also isolate problematic code and reproduce it in an online environment:

> - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) MySQL 5.6, Oracle 11g R2, PostgreSQL 9.6, PostgreSQL 9.3, SQLite (WebSQL), SQLite (SQL.js), SQL Server 2014

- Rextester: [SQL Server](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler), [PostgreSQL](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler), [MySql](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler), [Oracle](http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler)
- [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) Microsoft SQL Server 2016
- [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 8.0 PostgreSQL 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 10 SQLite 3.16, 3.17, 3.18
- [db <> fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/) MariaDB 10.2, 10.3, MySQL 8.0, Oracle 11.2, Postgres 8.4, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 10 and 11, SQLite 3.8, 3.16, SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017

---

It's also mentioned (sort of) when editing a tag wiki page, in the guidance widget on the top right:

> #### What are Tag Wikis?

> ...

> The **full tag wiki** is a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it:

> ...

> - important links for learning more